# Should I put the entire head tag and footer scripts inside the an include file?

Tags: html, header, dynamic-data

I currently only put my header design and footer design in separate include files, due to habit, but I do not put in the entire `<head></head>` and footer scripts inside.

This is because, in my mind, each page will have different titles / meta data and that some pages may have different scripts (some page need one script, the others don't). If all pages share one header, then all pages will share the same set of scripts which they might not need to use.

I know the advantage of all files sharing one header (with entire head tag in it) is that it's easy to apply a script across (if it's going to be used globally). Or say, if I add a new Google Font, all pages will be able to access it and I only change 1 file.

But how to handle the differences between each page? Is putting a condition / variable in those places that are dynamic a good practice? Just like in CMSes like Wordpress?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using server-side?  I've found that using a template engine which supports template inheritance is a great way to go.

Comment: You might consider using Smarty as a template engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, with the example for a home page:

```
<?php 
    // put metadata inside this array
    $pageData = array(
        'title' => 'my page title',
        'metaDataDescription' => 'my meta data for this page',
        'customAssets' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'js', 
                'src' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'
            )
        )
    );
    // include your header file now
    require_once 'header.php';
    ?>

    <div>
        This is where the unique content or HTML for this page should go.
        You could also include unique JavaScript here as well
    </div>
    <?php
        require_once 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

And then the `header.php` file could look like this:

```
<?php
// TODO add a null check for $pageData 
// and fill in with defaults
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $pageData['title'];?></title>
    <!-- add general css and js files here -->
    <?php
    foreach($pageData['customAssets'] as $index => $asset) {
       // TODO do some code to write out custom assets
       // ex:
       if($asset['type'] === "js") {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $asset['src'] . ' "></script>';
       }
    }?>

    <!-- use php to get meta data like title, description, keywords... ex: -->
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $pageData['metaDataDescription'];?>" />
    <!-- add favicon and whatever else in the header here -->
</head>
<body>
```